# google-tv emulator appears to start up logo screen, but then freeze the start up screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I did successfully created emulator for google-tv, but screen is freeze at start up logo screen

I attached two images for Emulator configuration and start up screen

Other Configuration :

Computer OS : Windows 7-64 bit

RAM         : 4 GB

1) Emulator configuration

.android\avd\Google_TV.ini :

- avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
- target=Google Inc.:Google TV Addon:13
- path=C:\<...>.android\avd\Google_TV.avd
- path.rel=avd\Google_TV.avd

[image]

2) Emulator's start up screen

[image]

This screen freeze and nothing go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got the solution by myself.**

I increase VH heap size : from 64 to 512

SD card size :1 GB

Comment: Now problem is that i can not get navigation bar on Home Page